# Copy highlighted cell and sheet name to destination worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy cell values that meet two conditions: (1) highlighted row, and (2) have a particular region code, e.g. "WA". Need to copy cell values from column B to the destination worksheet below the header in column A. In addition, copy the sheet name that corresponds to those values that meet those conditions to column C to the destination worksheet.

Problems I have encountered:

- As soon as I add this code it runs but doesn't past any values to the destination sheet. `LCase(Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value) = "wa"`
- If I remove the line of code above, and change the target area to look in column 2 `Set Target = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2))`, it will list the values that are highlighted in column B and paste them down starting on A1, instead of starting below the header.

Partial Target Area (full target area has different region codes and values going down these columns):

[image: Target Area]

```
Sub Criteria()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Last As Long
Dim Target As Range, Cell As Range, Dest As Range
Dim DestCounter As Long

' Delete the data off of AdvFilter sheet.
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AdvFilter").Range("A5:F5" & Last + 1).Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

'initialize destination counter
DestCounter = 1
Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AdvFilter")
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Visible = True Then

    Last = fLastRow(DestSh)

    With Sh
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set Target = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 2))
    End With

        For Each Cell In Target '<~ loop through each cell in the target space
            If AmIYellow(Cell) And Cell.Value <> "" And _
            LCase(Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value) = "wa" Then
              Set Dest = DestSh.Cells(Last + DestCounter, 1)
              Cell.Copy Dest
              DestCounter = DestCounter + 1
            End If
        Next Cell

    End If
Next Sh
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function fLastRow(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the data and not the formatting; you'll be better off using an array to collect the data and write all the data in one operation to the target range.

```
Sub Criteria()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim Data
    ReDim Data(1 To 2, 1 To 1)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AdvFilter")
        .Range(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp), "F5").Cells.Clear
    End With

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            With ws
                For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                    If LCase(r.Value) = "wa" And r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                        x = x + 1
                        ReDim Preserve Data(1 To 2, 1 To x)
                        Data(1, x) = r.Offset(0, 1)
                        Data(2, x) = ws.Name

                    End If
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AdvFilter")
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            If x > 0 Then .Resize(x, 2).Value = Application.Transpose(Data)

        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch, it works somewhat, but when I run it the first time, it writes the data starting in A4, which deletes part of my header. When I run it a second time, it will start on A5 like it should.

Comment: I'm not sure why about the inconsistency, but I'm glad you got it working.  Thanks for accepting my answer.  Happy coding!